# How can I redirect ports on an android device?

Tags: android, port

How can I redirect ports on an android device using code?

In the emulator this is done by the following commands:

1. run -> cmd -> telnet localhost 5554
2. redir add tcp:5000:6000

However I would like to know how to do this so the app works on physical devices as well.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible on a **non-rooted** device.

Comment: I have a rooted device but is still unable to use this code [link](www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/) on anything else other than two emulators.